# Cannot receive push notification from parse.com while app is closed

Tags: android, parsing, push-notification, parse-platform

Parse Push Notifications are working perfectly, but only when the app is open or in the background. I initialize and setDefaultPushCallback in the class that extends application and in the onCreate() method of that class. I don’t understand why it won’t send while it’s in the background.

Answer (score 0):

here is the manifiest file.....

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="your package name"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="15"
            android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="your package name.YourActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

            <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <receiver android:name="your package name.YourCustomReceiver" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                    <action android:name="your package name.UPDATE_STATUS" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```